# Record Triggered Flow Error- failure to insert records

Tags: salesforce, record

I am creating a flow where when an account gets deleted the related contact records will also be deleted and finally, the opportunity of the related account will update Account Name on opportunity to Unknown.

[image]

The error shows failure to insert account records. I am finding it hard to execute it since with the delete trigger one can only use fast field updates!